# SQL Data displayed in HTML table Php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have data extracted from the MYSQL table in the following format,

ABC 2016 567
ABC 2017 456
ABC 2018 987
DEF 2016 537
DEF 2017 452
EFG 2016 537
EFG 2017 452
EFG 2018 687

I need to display it in HTML table via Php in the following format,

SITE 2016 2017 2018
ABC 567 456 987
DEF 537 452
EFG 537 452 687

Any help would be appreciated.

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT sum(Volume) as Vol from rad_vol WHERE Modality like '%MR' group by Site, Year
```

Php Code:

```
    <?php
  $sql = "SELECT sum(Volume) as Vol from rad_vol WHERE Modality like '%MR' group by Site, Year ";
  echo $sql;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year from rad_vol";
  $res_year = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Site from rad_vol";
  $res_site = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<div id="content">
  <article>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            SITE
          </th>
          <?php
            if (mysqli_num_rows($res_year) > 0){
              $yr_count=0;
              while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res_year))
              {
                $year = $rows["Year"];
                echo '<th>' . $year . '</th>';
                $yr_count++;
              }
              echo $yr_count;
            }
          ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
          while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res_site))
          {
            echo '<tr><th>' . $rows["Site"] . '</th>';
            $i = 0;
            while($vols = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo '<td>' . $vols["Vol"] . '</td>';
              $i++;
              if ($i % 4 == 0){
                echo '</tr>';
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        ?>

      </thead>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you do the query better and make the results show as you want, then google how to echo HTML in php.

Comment: > insert *"hi and welcome to stack overflow please read the [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) gumph"* here <

Comment: You should rewrite the query. Mysql can group that data for you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that I am using. Would appreciate the help in this regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not a million miles off...

You can do it with a single query if you map that up to a couple of arrays and work with them.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
v.Site,
v.Year,
SUM(Volume) AS Vol 

FROM rad_vol AS v 

WHERE v.Modality LIKE '%MR' 

GROUP BY v.Site, v.Year
```

That should give you a recordset like this:

```
Site    Year    Vol
ABC     2016    567
ABC     2017    456
ABC     2018    987
DEF     2016    537
DEF     2017    452
EFG     2016    537
EFG     2017    452
EFG     2018    687
```

You can then loop through that recordset and push it into a couple of arrays:

```
$a = []; // this will be your data
$b = []; // this will be a list of years

if($response = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {

        // set the site to a var as we're going to use it
        // a couple of times
        $site = $row['Site'];

        // push the site onto the array as an index
        if(!array_key_exists($site, $a)) $a[$site] = [];

        // add the year and volumne to the site
        $a[$site][$row['Year']] = $row['Vol'];

        // add the year to the list if it's not already in
        if(!in_array($row['Year'], $b)) $b[] = $row['Year'];
    }
}
```

`$a` will hold your restructured data and `$b` is just a list of years. `$a` should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [ABC] => Array
        (
            [2016] => 567
            [2017] => 456
            [2018] => 987
        )

    [DEF] => Array
        (
            [2016] => 537
            [2017] => 452
        )

    [EFG] => Array
        (
            [2016] => 537
            [2017] => 452
            [2018] => 687
        )
)
```

The data is now structured much more like how you want to use it (if you tilt your head and squint). Now you just need to loop through for your output:

```
<div id="content">
    <article>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Site</th>
                    <!-- loop through the years -->
                    <?php foreach($b as $y): ?>
                    <th><?= $y; ?></th>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- loop through the sites -->
                <?php foreach($a as $siteName => $siteData): ?>
                <tr>
                    <!-- echo out the site name -->
                    <td><?= $siteName; ?></td>
                    <!-- 
                    loop through the years again so that the columns
                    are generated in the same way as they were for
                    the <thead> row
                    -->
                    <?php foreach($b as $y): ?>
                    <!--
                    check to see if *this* site has data for the current
                    year in the loop - if so echo that out in a <td>
                    otherwise just echo an empty <td>
                    -->
                    <td><?= array_key_exists($y, $siteData) ? $siteData[$y] : " "; ?></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </article>
</div>
```

---

**The whole kit and kaboodle**

This is just the dump of the complete script as it is on my dev box, with styling and comments removed.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', '******', '******', 'test');

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
v.Site,
v.Year,
SUM(Volume) AS Vol 

FROM rad_vol AS v 

WHERE v.Modality LIKE '%MR' 

GROUP BY v.Site, v.Year 
SQL;

$a = [];
$b = [];

if($response = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {

        $site = $row['Site'];
        if(!array_key_exists($site, $a)) $a[$site] = [];

        $a[$site][$row['Year']] = $row['Vol'];
        if(!in_array($row['Year'], $b)) $b[] = $row['Year'];
    }
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <article>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Site</th>
                            <?php foreach($b as $y): ?>
                            <th><?= $y; ?></th>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($a as $siteName => $siteData): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $siteName; ?></td>
                            <?php foreach($b as $y): ?>
                            <td><?= array_key_exists($y, $siteData) ? $siteData[$y] : " "; ?></td>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks much, this was exactly what I was looking for, with a couple of minor changes, the code worked perfectly and it shows data as requested. Now I am trying to understand the arrays and also will try to add a graph with moris.js. THANKS!!!